# Master/Detail - clear detail if object deleted or no objects left in Master (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, datasource, uisplitviewcontroller

In my iPad app (or iPhone 6 Plus in landscape) I am using a master/detail UISplitViewController.  When the user deletes the currently selected item from the Master or deletes all the items from the Master, the previously selected item's detail remains in the Detail view.

What do I need to do to ensure that if they delete the currently selected item or the last item in the data source (this might not be necessary) that the Detail view is cleared back to its empty, default state?

Is there a way for this to happen automatically through UITableView/DataSource magic?

(Swift please if possible, but Objective-C is OK too.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

store a Item property in master view.

```
var currentPresentingItem : <yourItemClass>?
```

`currentPresentingItem` is not nil only when detail view is presenting it. So, in normal iphone, people will never have a chance delete a item in masterView when `currentPresentingItem` is not nil

```
func segueToDefaultDetailViewIfPresentingItemDeleted(deletingItem : <yourItemClass>){
     if currentPresentingItem == deletingItem{
          // segue to your default detail view, 
          // this will never happen in normal iphone
     }
}
```

Comment: This worked great.  One note, I did the call to the segue in the case .Delete section of func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) in my fetched results controller delegate.

Comment: @Kent Lol, I do not know you are using CoreData, I will change the function name to make it certain